# Spring can't detect an entity to import

Tags: java, spring

I created new entity and while trying to make relation beetwen some other entity, I got an error because it can't find this class.

```
@Entity(name = "users")
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I'm talking about that OneToMany List posts, I can't import Post class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Long;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "users_id")
    private User author;
}
```

I have no idea why it's happening and how to solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I can't import Post class'? What error message do you get? Are the classes in the same package? What import statement did you try?

Comment: @TomStroemer the classes are in different packages both classes are public and just intellij highlight it on red and says "One to Many" value type should not be post

Comment: if the classes are in different packages, you should check if import <package-of-post>.Post; is added at the top of User class. if not, add it. Make sure the correct Post class is imported.

Comment: @SidharthBajpai It is added but it's blank, even tho I write it again, it's blank

Answer (score 0):

Just to let other knows if someone gonna have the same problem. Changing name of the entity helped and then changing it back.